# Error when deleting some properties of array objects typescript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects (firstList), now I am creating a new array (exportData) by clone the array firstList, with this new array I want to delete some of its properties and I do the following:

```
    let exportData = this.firstList;
    exportData = exportData.filter(function (props) {
      delete props.job;
      return true;
    });
```

Here I do not understand why even my old arrays are also deleting those properties, due to the mechanism or what did I do wrong?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SJ3aRaZ8oXFTHH7PZKwJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` is misused here because it doesn't actually filter anything, just iterates over array elements. For array iteration generic loop (`for`, `for..of`, `forEach`) should be used.

The problem here is that `props` object is not cloned. When it's modified, changes appear in every place where it's used.

The array should be mapped to shallow copies of objects where `job` property is omitted. This can be conventionally done with spread and rest syntax:

```
exportData = exportData.map(({ job, ...props}) => ({...props}));
```

Comment: Thank you, But I do not understand why when deleting some properties, the original will be affected, but when I use NewArray = [], the original is not affected.

Comment: exportData contains references to existing objects. They are same objects as in firstList, `exportData[0] === firstList[0]`. You modify these objects with `delete props.job`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating a copy of the array, you're creating a new reference to the same array. You need to create a new array and populate if with copies of the objects, as in boran's answer.

Comment: why when i set new array = [], it does not affect the original array

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The whole point of creating the new array is to avoid modifying the original.

Comment: I understood that I needed to create a new array. But I do not understand why when deleting some properties, the original will be affected, but when I use `NewArray = []`, the original  is not affected.

Comment: The concept you need to learn is *value vs reference*. I found this article for you, I think it explains it pretty well. https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Answer (score 1):

```
let newexportData = exportData.map(function (props) {
  let {job, ...other} = props;
  return other;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

exportData is **reference** of firstList. so when something is changed in exportData, they will be reflected in firstList. so, you need to clone the array.

you can do:

```
let exportData = [];
for(var i =0; i < this.firstList.length; i++){
  exportData[i] = this.firstList[i];
}
exportData = exportData.filter(function (props) {
  delete props.job;
  return true;
});
```

this is just a hint.

Comment: thanks you, but still not work, you can refer to the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working the way it should.

```
 let exportData = this.firstList;
```

you didn't create a new array , you just created one more reference to same array, it doesn't matter using which reference you are performing action because both are referring to same array.

If you try to clone in this way, it would be two different arrays,one copy of another and if there is any change on exportData, firstList will not be impacted.

```
let exportData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.firstList));
```